How to understand Generalised Riemann Invariants in conservation PDEs?
I am currently studying Riemann Solvers and Numerical Methods for Fluid Dynamics by Eleuterio F. Toro. In Chapter 2.4, the author introduces the concept of Generalized Riemann Invariants as follows:

The Generalised Riemann Invariants are relations that hold true, for certain waves, across the wave structure and lead to the following $(m-1)$ ordinary differential equations:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} w_1}{k_1^{(i)}}=\frac{\mathrm{d} w_2}{k_2^{(i)}}=\frac{\mathrm{d} w_3}{k_3^{(i)}}=\cdots=\frac{\mathrm{d} w_m}{k_m^{(i)}} \tag{2.123}
$$

However, this formulation appears rather abrupt and lacks clear motivation. I am curious about the derivation of these relations and why they are particularly applicable to the region across the $i$-th wave. Could you provide some insights into the underlying principles and the reasoning behind this approach?
